# Real time updates from Facebook with spring-social.io

Tags: java, facebook, spring

I don't like posting such a generic question, but I could not find any example on this topic in spring-social.io site ([here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)) and neither is SO (here)

Given the site description...this should be possible (extracted)

Features

```
A service provider and connection factory for use with Spring Social's connection framework.
An API binding for Facebook's Graph API.
**A real-time update controller for handling real-time update callbacks from Facebook.**
A disconnect controller to handle disconnect callbacks from Facebook.
Much more.
```

Thus, has anybody tried to make a real time update subscription using spring-socials.io? If so, any insights on how to do this will be very appreciated

Thanks,
Alejandro